# How to get count of elements from a web page which is having same properties using Blue prism?

Tags: blueprism

How to get the count of elements from a web page which is having same properties using Blue prism?

Like, in selenium we use the below,

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.LocatorStrategy("LocatorValue"));
int count = elements..size();
```

Any feature to find these in Blue prism, for an element captured in application modeller where the couple of properties are dynamic. ?

Comment: In BP you can easelly pass dynamic attributes to Application Modeller from a variable but I dont know if thats what you are asking.

Comment: Create a dynamic element to capture your elements. Then use `Read` stage and `Get Attributes` to get the count

Answer (score 0):

to do this task you will need to know the attributes you want to look for ahead of time and the values you'd like them to contain. Then the simple way of doing this is creating a 'mask' for the element you want by spying it and then making the values you are looking to match on either dynamic or static. If the value is the same throughout e.g. a DIV/SPAN or is dynamic but partially matches e.g. auto created element with tag ID like ID=333000XXXX then the following will work for both.

Make your elements in application modeler then in your object studio create a count data item

Now create a wait stage to check if your element exists, then use the 'Get Attribute' function to read the value you are looking for (used for the dynamic section as opposed to the static one), investigate on your value then if true increase count or if not true dont increase count and move to a wait stage

in this wait stage you'll want to configure it to wait for the element +1 to exist e.g. if you are spying DIV's you might spy it with match index being dynamic so you can supply a number here and check if the next match index exists before going back to start of loop and reading content/increasing count again.

by the end you'll have a simple loop with 2 wait stages either end, a read stage for dynamic values with a decision and calc to increase count or investigate on the attribute if needs be and then a data item which can be your output to show resultant count of found items on screen.

hope that helps